# how to get different colors of sea in matlab?

Tags: matlab

how to get different colors of sea in Matlab ??

swapping different colors of sea with Matlab of a satellite image, how we will get different colors of sea of a satellite image.A satellite image of world and water color is different in different areas / continents how will we get that all water part ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I recognize that English is most likely not your native tongue - but you cannot seriously expect that someone can answer your question in its current form. Do you want to segment sea from satellite images even though the color is changing? Please try to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, depending on what you want. A small list of techniques for satellite image recognition are: Image Segmentation, Edge Detection, Clustering and much more.

One of the more easy ways of changing the color is using color thresholding.

When the sea has a significant different color, you can filter it. See [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31118-color-segmentation-by-delta-e-color-difference) for a demo. More examples are [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/31862).

Basic steps:
You filter the sea/object using the library in the link.
When the filtering is done you get a black image (0 in the matrix) with the selected color/object as values in the matrix.

These values can be changed by matrix addition to the color you desire.

If you then combine (by matrix addition) both images again, you can highlight sea or other parts of an image.